# Twig Questions vs. Craft Questions

Tags: discussion

I notice that several questions being asked are more general twig questions than craft specific. Since twig is used as Craft's templating language I don't necessarily think these questions are inappropriate (e.g. subject to downvotes) but I was wondering if there was a general policy in place for handling these?

It seems like some more general twig questions might be more appropriate on the general StackOverflow site since it would benefit multiple communities that all share twig as a templating language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At what point would you separate the two though?  As soon as the question contains craft.something?

Personally, I don't think that it will detract much to answer Twig questions in the context of using it with Craft. Consider the case where someone is asking about a date formats or something that could be considered more PHPish, would we send them over to SO for that also?

I feel that it is more important to consider that the users of this SE will be / are coming here to ask questions about Craft and learn how to use it effectively in that context.

You should also consider that we need all the activity we can, to pass out of beta phase; if we start referring questions about Craft or any of its layers to SO, that might discourage the level of participation we need to get out of Beta.

Comment: Since no twig questions have been down-voted, I would agree that seems to be the general consensus. It could get pretty arbitrary as to what is Twig vs. Craft. Still, thought it was worth officially asking. :)

Comment: What would you say about this now closed question, [How to get all matches of regex?](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/228/how-to-get-all-matches-of-regex). Leave open?

Comment: I'd leave it open. Craft and Twig really go hand in hand, some functions/filters are even added by Craft itself. And I think basic twig questions won't come up that often.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like everyone generally agrees: "Twig questions are OK here." Just wanted to make an additional point... It's sometimes hard to know where **native-Twig** ends and **Craft-modified-Twig** begins.

Craft has expanded upon the native Twig implementation, adding new [Functions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/functions), [Filters](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters), and [Tags](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/tags).

Each one of those documentation pages starts with a sentence like this one:

> On top of the template filters that Twig comes with, Craft provides a few of its own.

It's very common for a solution to require a combination of native-Twig syntax and Craft-Twig syntax.

Which is all a very long way of saying, **yes, Twig questions belong here**.